# Logging on to Wifi using Xbox 360 Slim

Tags: xbox-360

I recently bought my first Xbox 360 Slim. When connecting to Internet, my ISP redirects me to a web page which asks me for a User ID/ Password. I get access when I enter that info.

Now when I try to connect to the internet using my Xbox it is able to connect to the network but to the the net (Xbox Live). The reason for this is that it never takes me to the web based login page.

Is there any way I can connect to Xbox Live (without changing my ISP)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to use browser-based logins with the 360.

The option most people choose is to connect to wifi using a laptop (or desktop), log in via the laptop browser and then share that internet connection over ethernet. On Windows 7, this is a function called ICS (internet connection sharing) for which there are numerous good tutorials on the internet. On a Mac, this is called "Internet sharing" in the Sharing preference pane. They're both pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be ISP specific and thus a good question to call and ask your ISP.  The xbox contains no browser functionality, so unless they have an alternative route to internet access (a different DNS setting) I would guess your out of luck.

Call your ISP directly and ask them about it.

Comment: unfortunately my isp does not have an option to override the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a router? If not, the ISP may be keeping track of "authorized computers" through their MAC addresses. If that's the case (and I'm not really sure what other way they could be doing it) you have two options:

1. Have your PC and 360 go through a router so that they'd both have the same MAC address - the router's.
2. Temporarily change/spoof your PC's MAC address so that it matches the 360's. After authorizing on your PC with a spoofed MAC, the 360 should then work.

Comment: If he has to log in so frequently, there is probably an expiration of the MAC address.  This would make spoofing a MAC address a temporary solution (until it's authentication expired) and a serious pain in the butt to do constantly